# How do I make processData function wait for the results from my getData function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, observable

My getData function makes an api call, then puts each returned object into an array. The array is then returned. I now need my processData function to await the results from the getData function and then further process it. Currently I dont get any results when I `console.log(cleaningData)`What am I doing wrong with async/await? What am I missing?

```
getData() {
 var dataBucket = [] 
 this.https.get('https:******FAKEURL*******').subscribe((response: any) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    for(let i = 0 ; i < response.data.length ; i++) {
       dataBucket.push(response.data[i])
    }
  });
  console.log(dataBucket);
  return dataBucket;     
 }

async processData() { 
  let cleaningData = await this.getData();
  console.log(cleaningData);
  //do something with cleaningData
}
```

Comment: You `await this.getData()`, but `getData` isn't an `async` function and doesn't otherwise return a promise.

Comment: I suggest you learn the basics of angular observables and pipes , it is a very powerful subject that can help achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular you normally follow another logic for async functions. You declare what should happen when an asynchronous function returns with a subscription. So what should happen when it returns start from your subscription block of code (not from somewhere else where you wait for your asunchronous function)

```
    getData() {
    
        this.https.get('https:******FAKEURL*******').subscribe((response: any) => {
            
            var dataBucket = []   <-----this should be here declared
    
            console.log(response.data)
    
            for(let i = 0 ; i < response.data.length ; i++){
             
              dataBucket.push(response.data[i])
            }
    
          this.processData(response)  <-------you call that here
          });
      }
    
    processData(response: any){    <-----you don't need async and await
    
      // <----- here you can do anything with the response from getData() 
    
      console.log(cleaningData);
    
      //do something with cleaningData
   }
```